# Question about Taylor's Theorem

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I am reading a proof from my professor (proof of convergence of Secant Method in Numerical Analysis), and she makes use of Taylor series. We have a function $f \in C^2(a, b)$, and a point $z \in (a, b)$. She writes 
$$f(z+h) = f(z) + f'(z)h + \dfrac {f''(z)}{2}h^2 + O(h^3).$$

However, I don't understand how we get this result.

I thought that Taylor's Theorem said: Let $f \in C^{k+1}(a, b)$. Then for every $z \in (a, b)$ and for every $h$ satsifying $z+h \in (a, b)$, we have
$$f(z+h) = f(z) + f'(z)h + \cdots + \dfrac {f^{(k)}(z)}{k!}h^k + \dfrac {f^{(k+1)}(\xi_h)}{(k+1)!} h^{k+1}$$
for some $\xi_h$ between $z$ and $z+h$.

Thus, if $f \in C^2(a, b)$, I could see us writing
$$f(z+h) = f(z) + f'(z)h + \dfrac {f''(\xi_h)}{2}h^2$$
and (I guess assuming the second derivative is bounded) we could write
$$f(z+h) = f(z) + f'(z)h + O(h^2)$$

However, I don't understand how to get what my professor wrote.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you stop at the square term? In your use of Taylor's theorem, we can say
$$
f(z+h)=f(z)+f'(z)h + \frac{f''(z)}{2!}h^2 + \frac{f'''(\xi_h)}{3!}h^3.
$$
The last term is $O(h^3)$ since obviously $h^3$ is, and for the other term in the product, $z\leq \xi_h\leq z+h$ so as $h\to 0$, we see that $\frac{f'''(\xi_h)}{3!}\to \frac{f'''(z)}{3!}=O(1).$

Comment: Well because in the theorem that we were proving, we assumed that $f \in C^2(a, b)"$ (I mentioned this in the first paragraph, sorry if it got lost in there). So I think the last term should be with $f''$, no?

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for missing it. The correct way to set up the problem (under your professor's $O(h^3)$ premise) is that $f \in C^2([a,b])$ and $f''$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$. I got that set up straight from Rudin's Analysis book which is right in front of me. Most likely, your professor just omitted the differentiable part. Your answer isn't wrong, but obviously knowing a third derivative tells you more information.

Answer (score 1):

You an also write
$$
f(z+h)=f(z)+f'(z)h+\frac{f''(z)h^2}2+\frac{h^2}2(f''(\zeta_h)-f(z))
$$
and by $f\in C^2$ you get that the last term is $o(h^2)$, which might still be sufficient for your purposes. To get $O(h^3)$ from this approach, you need that $f''$ is Lipschitz, that is, $f\in C^{2,1}([a,b])$.